# Use mapply to generate plots using column names as argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, mapply

The data of interest are in `mymeanDT`

```
DT <- data.table(yearmonth = as.yearmon(sample(seq(as.Date('2012/07/01'), as.Date('2016/02/28'),by="day"), 5000, replace = TRUE)),
             mydummy = as.factor(rbinom(5000, 1, .4)), X = runif(5000, 0, 1), Y = rnorm(5000, 20, 5), Z = runif(5000, 4, 6))

mymeanDT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(mydummy, yearmonth), .SDcols = c("X", "Y", "Z")]
```

I need to plot lines for all columns, by `yearmonth` and by `mydummy`. I can do that with the following

```
mycolnames <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
my_lapply_plots <- lapply(mymeanDT[, mycolnames, with = FALSE],function(mycol)
    ggplot(mymeanDT, aes(x = yearmonth,y = mycol)) +  
    geom_line(aes(linetype = mydummy, color = mydummy)) + scale_x_yearmon() + xlab("") + ylab("") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = -0.03)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash", "solid"), breaks=c(0,1),labels=c("N", "Y")) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#701B45", "#007FAE"), breaks=c(0,1),labels=c("N", "Y")) +
    ggtitle(paste("Some", "title", sep = " "))
)
```

I would like to use the column names in the title. So I tried passing a similar function through `mapply`

```
my_mapply_plots <- mapply(function(mycol, mynames) 
    ggplot(mymeanDT, aes(x = yearmonth,y = mycol)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = mydummy, color = mydummy)) + scale_x_yearmon() 
    + xlab("") + ylab("") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = -0.03)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash", "solid"), breaks=c(0, 1), 
         labels=c("N", "Y")) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#701B45", "#007FAE"), breaks=c(0, 1), 
         labels=c("N", "Y")) +
    ggtitle(paste("Some", mycolnames, sep = " ")),
  mycol = mymeanDT[, mycolnames, with = FALSE], mynames = mycolnames)
```

But this is the output I get

```
my_mapply_plots
```

> ```
>             X      Y      Z     
> data        List,5 List,5 List,5
> layers      List,1 List,1 List,1
> scales      ?      ?      ?     
> mapping     List,2 List,2 List,2
> theme       List,1 List,1 List,1
> coordinates ?      ?      ?     
> facet       ?      ?      ?     
> plot_env    ?      ?      ?     
> labels      List,6 List,6 List,6
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should loop over the `mycolnames`-vector with `lapply` to get the desired plots. Using:

```
lapply(mycolnames, function(column) {
  ggplot(data = mymeanDT,
         aes(x = yearmonth, y = mymeanDT[[ column ]], linetype = mydummy, color = mydummy)) +
    geom_line()  + scale_x_yearmon() +
    ggtitle(paste("Some", column, sep = " "))
})
```

will get you 3 plots.

The first one:

[image]

If you want to store that:

```
myplots <- lapply(mycolnames, function(column) {
  ggplot(data = mymeanDT,
         aes(x = yearmonth, y = mymeanDT[[ column ]], linetype = mydummy, color = mydummy)) +
    geom_line()  + scale_x_yearmon() +
    ggtitle(paste("Some", column, sep = " "))
})
```

Typing `myplots` will then print the three plots. You can then also access the plots individually with `myplots[[1]]` (or: `myplots[1]`)